# If I set my phone to "vibrate mode" and I then receive phone calls, can the vibration damage my device?

Tags: vibration

Do you know if it's a good idea to set the vibration to be almost continuous on my phone when I receive calls?

I am asking this because I am worried about breaking the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think continuous vibration while the phone is ringing can destroy a phone. It can drain battery though. I always set mine to vibrate, and it's still fine.

Some phones or custom ROMs let you adjust how strong the vibration is.

Comment: The only thing I can think of adding is that vibrate is a motor so if it is used more often it would burn out quicker. Realistically though I use it all the time myself and no issue at all.